# SQL Server: Temporal tables and adding computed columns at runtime

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns, temporal-tables

Basically, I want to create computed columns at runtime in temporal tables, for this I had to follow those steps:

1. Turn System_Versioning to off
2. Alter tempral and add the computed column
3. Turn System Versioning to on

Here's an example:
I have a temporal table 'FTWV' with a history table 'FTWVHistory', the content of the computed columns will be extracted from a json column 'Data'

```
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FTWV] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FTWV] ADD [Identity] AS JSON_VALUE([Data], '$.Identity'); 
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FTWV] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[FTWVHistory]));
```

When I execute the above queries I get the following error message :

> Setting SYSTEM_VERSIONING to ON failed because table 'DatabaseName.dbo.FTWV' has 5 columns and table 'DatabaseName.dbo.FTWVHistory' has 4 columns.

So, I guessed if I Just add the same computed column to the 'FTWVHisotry' table it would work

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FTWV] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FTWV] ADD [Identity] AS JSON_VALUE([Data], '$.Identity'); 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FTWVHISTORY] ADD [Identity] AS JSON_VALUE([Data], '$.Identity'); 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FTWV] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[FTWVHistory]));
```

But I get another when executing the last line (setting system_versioning to on) :

> Setting SYSTEM_VERSIONING to ON failed because history table 'DatabaseName.dbo.FTWVHistory' has computed column specification. Consider dropping all computed column specifications and trying again.

Comment: https://bornsql.ca/blog/temporal-tables-and-how-to-deal-with-computed-columns/

Comment: The answer to the duplicate explains that the history table column can't be calculated but have same type as the formula's result. The history table stores a snapshot of the actual values at a specific point in time. The expression of a calculated column is part of the *schema* though. To support calculated columns it would have to store the schema as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a computed column to a temporal table. Instead you need to turn off system versioning and then add the *computed* column to your system versioned table and then a column with the *same* data type to your history table.

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FTWV] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FTWV] ADD [Identity] AS JSON_VALUE([Data], '$.Identity'); 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FTWVHISTORY] ADD [Identity] nvarchar(4000);
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FTWV] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[FTWVHistory]));
```

As a side note, as `JSON_VALUE` returns an `nvarchar(4000)` I would suggest *explicitly* `CAST`ing/`CONVERT`ing your computed column to the appropriate data type, and then creating the column (in your history table) with that data type.